# как найти произведение в матрице ,ниже главной диагонали

Tags: python

суть такова - задается размер массива(NxN),заполняется случайными числами,а далее надо найти произведение всех чисел которые лежат ниже главной диагонали.Не понимаю как вычислить произведение

```
from random import randint
z = 1
N = int(input())
x = [[0]*N for i in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
   for c in range(N):
      x[i][c] = randint(1, 100)
for v in range(len(x)):
   print(x[v])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это должно сработать.

```
result = 1
for a in range(len(x)):
   for b in range(len(x[a])):
      if a > b:
         result *= x[a][b]
print(result)
```